# refresh div on adding rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My table is being populated using ajax from a mysql database. I have a text field below it which adds the entered data to the database. All this works fine, but what i want to do is on adding that new row to the table, i want to dynamically show the user that their entry has been added (or simply refresh that div when new field has been added). Currently aim able to achieve that using a simple function:

```
function addItem(new_item, edit_table) {
     var itemName = new_item;
     var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
     var rowCell = document.createElement('td');
     rowCell.textContent = itemName;
     // rowCell.addClass("grid");
     newRow.appendChild(rowCell);
     edit_table.appendChild(newRow);
  }
```

However this does not let me add extra functionalities to that row e.g. i have a delete and edit icon upon hover. So by using this function i am able to show the new row added but its not exactly functioning. So i recon the better option would be to refresh that div when this happens.

I am using the following code to call the addItems method:

```
$('#b_go').click(function(){
    //some other conditions, then using ajax to post the data
    success: function (data) {
    if(data == 'success') {
        addItem(new_row, selected_table);
   }
```

HTML for the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered home" id="subjects">
    <thead>
        <th>Subject Title</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $sql = mysql_query("select Title from Subject");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['Title']?> <!--using html to output buttons for delete and edit for each row-->
         <?;echo "</td></tr>";
        }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Css for the above table:

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.table th, .table td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table th {
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.table thead:first-child tr th, .table thead:first-child tr td {
  border-top: 0;
}

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td, .table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.home {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}

.home th {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #039;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;
}
.home td {
    line-height:15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #404040;
    padding: 9px 8px 3px 8px;
}
.home tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color:#E6E6FF;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to handle hover events? Like newRow.onblur='someFunction()'

Comment: No, all i want to do is refresh that table (div), so that i can get all the functionalists for the new row that are present in the existing rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to leave work, but here's a quick and dirty answer.

When adding new elements dynamically that have pre-existing functions/events/actions that are already bound,  the new elements will not automatically inherent the events/actions of their siblings.  I recommend using jQuery for something like this.

**For jQuery versions greater than 1.3 - use jQuery LIVE() function:**
http://api.jquery.com/live/

*Description:  This will map the data passed to your new event handlers needed*

**For jQuery versions 1.7 or higher - use jquery ON() function:**

http://api.jquery.com/on/

*Description: method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object.  This will attach the event handler to any new element you create.*

**Update: 11:57 AM Tuesday:  Based on your comment.  You need to use bind('click') or on('') function when you SUBMIT the form.**

```
 // First : Change your click code to this. You'll need the bind() function here.  This will make it so your events will bind to each new row

   $('#b_go').bind("click", function(){
        //some other conditions, then using ajax to post the data
        success: function (data) {
        if(data == 'success') {
        addItem(new_row, selected_table);
   }

 // Change your function to this:
    function addItem(new_item, edit_table) {
        var itemName = new_item;
        var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
        var rowCell = document.createElement('td');
        rowCell.textContent = itemName;
         $(rowCell).addClass("grid"); // Make sure GRID is the class being applied to your other TDs/TRs etc
        newRow.appendChild(rowCell);
        edit_table.appendChild(newRow);
       $(edit_table +' tr:odd td').css('background','#f9f9f9'); // Set color for all odd rows.

  }
```

**HOW TO RELOAD TABLE:**

STEP #1 - **Create a new < div > layer** with an ID #getDataGrid.  **THIS MUST WRAP AROUND YOUR TABLE.**

STEP #2 - **Create a new file like** : **data-grid.php** and include the following HTML.  Please also include any PHP business logic that would be needed to make the appropriate database calls to make this code successful:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered home" id="subjects">
    <thead>
        <th>Subject Title</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php
        $sql = mysql_query("select Title from Subject");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['Title']?> <!--using html to output buttons for delete and edit for each row-->
         <?;echo "</td></tr>";
        }
            ?>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

STEP #3  : **Update your click function:**

```
$('#b_go').bind("click", function(){
        //some other conditions, then using ajax to post the data
        success: function (data) {
        if(data == 'success') {

        addItem(new_row, selected_table);

        $.get('data-grid.php', function(getTable) {
            $('#getDataGrid').html(getTable);
        });

   }
```

EXPLANATION.  What this is doing on your click function is using jQuery to essentially perform a "GET" (just as PHP GET would perform).  We are retrieveing our newly created data-grid.php file, and then PLACING the contents into the #getDataGrid div layer we created that wraps around the table.  What this will do will actually wipe out the currently displayed table with the new displayed table.

Comment: I do not want to attach any events here. I want to refresh my div to retain the functions of my table, e.g. my table has striped rows (alternative colour for rows using css) but my dynamically adding the row it doesn't achieve that.

Comment: I have updated my code based on what you said.  Now, the reason your alternating rows are not showing up is because you are not duplicating your css classes applied to your table.  As to the behaviour for your functions of your table (edit/delete/update functions) you need to reference the code above in the "UPdate" section of my response.  For your table rows you need to re-apply any classes that are pre-existing on other < TD > elements.  so for instance.  $("TDyouCreated").addClass("greyBG");

Comment: I have updated my answer based on what you said, hopefully this will give you a much clearer picture of what i want to achieve, i am able to call the method. However the adding class didn't really work as you can see in my code comment.

Comment: Hi Namit,  I have updated my code accordingly.  Please see Update: 10:39 AM Tuesday updates

Comment: You were right, that was my div class actually, i tried using the table class too, but as you said that wouldn't work. I have updated my question with the HTML of the table this time. Just out of curiosity, how does bind actually make a difference?

Comment: Oh got the bind part, just read your answer properly again! :P

Comment: Try my new solution listed in my update... I added a .css() property to your javascript with commentary.  If that doesn't work  i'll also need to see the CSS for the following HTML : <table class="table table-striped table-bordered home" id="subjects">.  I need to see where your table rows are alternating color

Comment: Haha, no problem, i thought i was being a pain instead. I have updated the post with the css, there are a few more elements but i don't think they are necessary in this case.

Comment: Hello, try my updated JavaScript and let me know if it gives you the desired results for alternating colors

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. :(
Sorry about this but i just realised that we have gone off-topic here. As you can see from my code above, i am also getting delete and edit buttons for each row. But doing this i won't be able to achieve that. However if i manage to reload my table or div. This problem can be solved.

Comment: I have updated this problem with a 3 STEP process that should "refresh" the table as you need it.

Comment: I almost did the same thing, except instead of using get. I am using `.load()` to call that php file which reloads that div.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only partially using a DOM approach, create the TD in javascript too.

```
function addItem(itemName) {

    var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
    var rowCell = documentcreateElement('td');
    rowCell.textContent = itemName;
    newRow.appendChild(rowCell);
    document.getElementById('subjects').appendChild(newRow);

}
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything though!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `JQuery`? You can make something similar in `JS`, but here's the concept.

1. Create a template of the new row in `HTML`
2. Add the row to the `DB`.
3. Add the row to the table:

   ```
   var row = $("#myRowTemplate").clone();
   row.attr("id", "");
   //Bind the new data
   row.find(".fname").text("Jack");
   row.find(".lname").text("Dean");
   //Bind a click event on the first name
   row.find(".fname").click(function(){alert('Hi!');});
   $("#myTable").find("tbody :first").append(row);
   ```

Hopes that's helps :)